# python split string by multiple delimiters and/or combination of multiple delimiters

Tags: python

Input:

```
x = "121, 1238,\nxyz,\n 123abc \n\rabc123"
```

I want to split This string with the delimiters `",", "\n", "\r", "\s"` to get the output

```
['121', '1238', 'xyz', '123abc', 'abc123']
```

Whatever I try, the delimiters are accepted as single characters and not as combination of characters.
e.g.

1.

```
re.split("\n|,|\s|\r", x)
```

Gave output of

```
['121', '', '1238', '', 'xyz', '', '', '123abc', '', '', 'abc123']
```

2. `re.split("\n\s|,|\s|\r", x)`

Gave output of

```
['121', '', '1238', '', 'xyz', '', '123abc', '', 'abc123']
```

The second one is a slight improvement over the first one. But if that's what is required, I need to give all possible combinations manually.

something Like (with more combinations):

```
re.split("\n\s|\s\n|\s\n\s|\n|,\s|\s,|\s,\s|,|\s|\r", x)
```

output:

```
['121', '1238', 'xyz', '', '123abc', '', 'abc123']
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `re.split("[\s,]+",  x)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Can you add it as the answer and explain what's going on? There is no `\n` or `\r`, still how it splits on everything?

Comment: @RatDon have a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: @RatDon specifically look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#:~:text=which%20includes%20%5B%20%5Ct%5Cn%5Cr%5Cf%5Cv%5D%2C%20and%20also%20many%20other%20characters)

Comment: @alfinkel24 Thanks. That clarifies everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining [@Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp)'s and [@alfinkel24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828098/alfinkel24)'s comments:

```
re.split("[\s,]+",  x)
```

Will split the string as required to

```
['121', '1238', 'xyz', '123abc', 'abc123']
```

**Explanation:**

- `[...]` any of the characters.
- `+` one or more repetitions of the previous characters.
- `\s` any white space characters including `"\n, \r, \t"`

  *Official documentation:*

> \s
>
> For Unicode (str) patterns:
> Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes [ \t\n\r\f\v], and also many other characters, for example the non-breaking spaces mandated by typography rules in many languages). If the ASCII flag is used, only [ \t\n\r\f\v] is matched.
>
>     For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
> Matches characters considered whitespace in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to [ \t\n\r\f\v].

Answer (score 1):

Allow `re.split` to take as a delimiter 1 or more repetitions of any of your delimiting characters:

```
>>> re.split("[,\s]+", x)
['121', '1238', 'xyz', '123abc', 'abc123']
```

(The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy, they match as much as they can.)